# Not able to import data through nsepy

Tags: python, nsepy

I am trying to import the nsepy library to get the data of state bank of india stock (SBIN) for the year 2018, but get an error.

Code:

```
from nsepy import get_history               
import datetime as dt                       

sbi_df = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=dt.date(2018, 1, 1), end=dt.date(2018, 12, 31))
print(sbi_df)
```

Error i am getting:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\commons.py", line 132, in run
self.run()
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\commons.py", line 132, in run
    self.result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 138, in get_history
    self.result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 138, in get_history
    return get_history_quanta(**kwargs)    
return get_history_quanta(**kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 143, in get_history_quanta
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 143, in get_history_quanta
    df = url_to_df(url=url,
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 151, in url_to_df
    df = url_to_df(url=url,
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 151, in url_to_df
    resp = url(**params)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\commons.py", line 167, in __call__
    resp = url(**params)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\commons.py", line 167, in __call__
    return self.session.get(url, params=kwargs, proxies = self.proxy )
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.session.get(url, params=kwargs, proxies = self.proxy )
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 723, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 723, in <listcomp>
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 723, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 191, in resolve_redirects
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 723, in <listcomp>
    raise TooManyRedirects(
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 191, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects(
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\commons.py", line 132, in run
    self.result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 138, in get_history
    return get_history_quanta(**kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 143, in get_history_quanta
    df = url_to_df(url=url,
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 151, in url_to_df
    resp = url(**params)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\commons.py", line 167, in __call__
    return self.session.get(url, params=kwargs, proxies = self.proxy )
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 723, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 723, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 191, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects(
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\commons.py", line 132, in run
    self.result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 136, in get_history
    return pd.concat((t1.result, t2.result))
AttributeError: 'ThreadReturns' object has no attribute 'result'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\12_Day\1_nsepy.py", line 4, in <module>
    sbi_df = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=dt.date(2018, 1, 1), end=dt.date(2018, 12, 31))
  File "E:\Quantitative_Trading_Programme\venv\lib\site-packages\nsepy\history.py", line 136, in get_history
    return pd.concat((t1.result, t2.result))
AttributeError: 'ThreadReturns' object has no attribute 'result'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: "Too many redirects" indicates a possible redirection loop at the target site. You'll want to try to debug this in a simpler program without threads etc.